# Cucumber simple click_link works in one and fails in another scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I've got a problem with Cucumber test for a simple click_link.

On my "show" view page i've link that looks like this

```
<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

And i've got 2 scenarios that use it, one that fails is

```
When I click "Back"
Then i must see page with title "New Post"
```

This one fails, basically Cucumber goes to New Post link first, inserts details, Submits new post and then clicks "Back". That is where i get error

```
undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Other scenario that uses same Link on same Page is

```
When I click "Back"
Then i must see page with title "All Posts"
```

Although this scenario and step works fine..

So what could be the problem? Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: In the new view or new controller, something that `empty?` is called upon is `nil`. What is it that `empty?` is called on?

Comment: I've figured it out, it was calling "Back" button which was empty? due to button being redirected to :back path. And in cucumber test enviroment stuff doesnt' get saved, so at that point it had no :back path